# Logstash doesnt read from configured input file

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to configure my Logstash to read from a specified log file. When I configure it to read from stdin it works as expected, my input results in a message from Logstash and displays in my Kibana UI.

```
$ cat /tmp/logstash-stdin.conf 
input {
  stdin {}
}
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }

}

$./logstash -f /tmp/logstash-stdin.conf
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path //usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs errors to the console
The stdin plugin is now waiting for input:
hellloooo
{
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "myhost.com",
    "@timestamp" => 2017-11-17T16:05:41.595Z,
       "message" => "hellloooo"
}
```

However, when I run Logstash with a file input I get no indication that the file is loaded into Logstash, and it does not show in Kibana.

```
$ cat /tmp/logstash-simple.conf 
input {
  file {
    path => "/tmp/test_log.txt"
    type => "syslog"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}


$ ./logstash -f /tmp/logstash-simple.conf 
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path //usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs errors to the console
```

Any suggestions of how I can troubleshoot why my Logstash is not ingesting the configured file?

Comment: But are you writing to the file after starting Logstash?

Comment: I am not, didn't realize this was necessary... but it works when I do. Is there not an option to read an existent log file?

Comment: @mustaccio any suggestion how I configure logstash to read from a folder? When I change my configuration to the following, nothing is ingested regardless of if the folder has a file in it when logstash is started, I modifiy the file when logstash is running, or I move a new file to the folder while logstash is running:   file {
    path => "/tmp/logstash_input/*.*"
    start_position => beginning

  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the file input plugin starts reading at the end of the file, so only lines added after Logstash starts will be processed. To read all existing lines upon startup add the option `"start_position" => "beginning"` to the configuration, as [explained in documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-start_position).

Comment: thanks, this worked. any suggestion how I configure logstash to read from a folder? When I change my configuration to the following, nothing is ingested regardless of if the folder has a file in it when logstash is started, I modifiy the file when logstash is running, or I move a new file to the folder while logstash is running: file { path => "/tmp/logstash_input/*.*" start_position => "beginning" }

Comment: Logstash remembers where it has stopped reading a file and won't read that part again. So if a file has already been read, it won't be read again. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html. You can configure `sincedb_path=>/dev/null` so that logstash don't save what has been read.